# C++11: Guaranteeing nonconverting reference from template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion

So I have a struct X:

```
struct X
{
    int typecode;
    char* pData;
    int length;
    ...
}
```

and a long list of types, we'll call this set TS.  TS includes most primitive types and several class types.

For each type T in TS I have a regular function defined:

```
void setup(X& x, const T& t);
```

For example for T = string setup looks like:

```
void setup(X& x, const string& s)
{
    x.typecode = X_STRING;
    x.pData = s.c_str();
    x.length = s.size();
    ...
}
```

Now I have a template function convert_to_x:

```
template<class T>
X convert_to_x(const T& t)
{
    X x;
    memset(x, 0, sizeof(x));
    setup(x, t);
    return x;
}
```

And a function f that takes an array of X:

```
void f(X* xs, int num_args);
```

And further a variadic template function `g`:

```
template<class... Args)
void g(Args... args)
{
    constexpr num_args = sizeof...(args);

    X xs[] = { convert_to_x(args)... };

    f(xs, num_args);
}
```

What is going on is that you can call g with any number of parameters and types and it will convert the parameters to an array of X type, and then call f.

The problem is that if g is called with a type that is not in TS, but is convertible to a type in TS, the following happens:

1. A converting constructor is called to create a temporary t.
2. `setup` will store a pointer to this temporary.
3. the temporary is destroyed.
4. f is called with an xs that contains hanging pointers.

I need a way at entry to `g` to convert any arguments that are convertible to a type in TS but are not of a type in TS, and keep them around for the whole scope of `g`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

**Update:**

One way I just thought of that may work is to define a regular function `convert` for each type T in TS as follows:

```
T convert(const T& t) { return t; }
```

and then define a wrapper for g:

```
template<class... Args>
void g2(Args... args)
{
    g(convert(args)...);
}
```

but I think this will cause unnecessary copying of types that are already in TS and don't need converting.  Is there some way to use rvalue/lvalue semantics to avoid this?

**Update 2:**

Maybe this would work:

For each T in TS:

```
const T& convert(const T& t) { return t; }
T convert(const T&& t) { return t; }
```

then:

```
template<class... Args>
void g2(Args... args)
{
    g(convert(args)...);
}
```

Are there any cases where setup could possibly receive a temporary with the above?

Comment: It might be worth defining a type-trait-like `struct X_compatible<T>;` to make it easy to set up `static_assert`s and SFINAE `enable_if`s as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can add deleted overloads for `setup`:

```
void setup(X& x, const string& s) = delete;
```

Since rvalue references bind to temporaries more readily than const lvalue references, calling `setup` with a temporary will select the overload with rvalue references. But since this `setup` overload is deleted, it would be illegal to actually call it. So when `g` is called with the wrong type of argument, the line `X xs[] = { convert_to_x(args)... };` requires `convert_to_args` to call a deleted version of `setup`, so that instantiation fails. In turn, it causes the particular instantiation of `g` to fail as well.

### Edit

Looking at your update #2, this should work. Since `convert` already causes the best conversion to one of the `TS`, `g` should never be called with unwanted types. So no temporaries would be created by unwanted conversions upon the invocation of `setup`. Thus, any temporaries would be arguments to `g`, and would be guaranteed to live for the duration of `g`.

### Edit 2

You're right that `T convert(const T&& t) { return t; }` could result in values being unnecessarily copied. But this is easily fixed:

```
const T& convert(const T& t) { return t; }
const T&& convert(const T&& t) { return std::move(t); }
```

you won't get any copying of values. Lifetime of temporaries is correct, too, since temporaries live until the end of the full expression in which they are created:

```
template<class... Args>
void g2(Args... args)
{
    g(convert(args)...);
} //          ^^^^ temporaries created by a conversion here will live until g returns
```

Comment: This is useful to prevent the hanging pointers, thanks - however with this g will not be able to be called with types not in TS, but convertible to a member of TS (I think). Is this right?  Is there a way to change g (or wrap it) so that it will make the conversion only if necessary. (see my update)

Comment: Does this really work? Perhaps I am confused, but doesn't the conversion (to a temporary) happen when `setup()` is called, rather than when `convert_to_x()` is called, because `convert_to_x()` is a template, so `T` will be assumed to be whatever the actual type of the argument is?

Comment: @jogojapan: Yes, actually you are right I think.  To implement this solution I would need to delete the rvalue overloads of setup, not of convert_to_x.

Comment: @jogojapan: That's what I thought at first, but first some reason I told myself "No, that's wrong"! I'll fix it.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: Update 2 almost works.  The only problem I see is that a parameter t of type T in TS that is an rvalue reference (because it is a temporary or xvalue at the call of g2) will be unnecessarily copied by the rvalue version of convert.  Not sure how to get around that one.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: If possible, it is actually moved, which is generally efficient enough to be acceptable. Though, in case it isn't accept, and to do justice to your question, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: As a final point: If you had stuck with pass-by-value, this ugly problem with temporaries would never have manifest itself. I'd be interested to see if (and how often) the major compilers perform copy-elision on function calls with temporaries as arguments. Also interesting would be whether move semantics eliminate the concern for excessive copying in this scenario.